# Testing cordova plugins without device

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I think I know the answer to this question already but thought I would throw it out there incase there was a workaround....

Just built a ionic app with ngcordova, which works fine and I have tested on my android device and deployed to playstore.

Just in the process of deploying to the apple app store. I currently don't have an apple ios physical device to test the cordova plugins.

I am using sms, camera and local notification. These as far as am aware cannot be tested in the ios simulator in xcode.

Don't really want to spend £400 on a tablet to test one app..  any one had the same problem and found a means of testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test plugins in iOS simulator.

**edit:** I just stumbled upon [the official documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage) where it states that even with Ionic View you can test these plugins:

- com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin 1.0.3 "Brodysoft SQLitePlugin"
- com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.3 "Keyboard"
- com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner 1.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
- org.apache.cordova.battery-status 0.2.12 "Battery"
- org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.4 "Camera"
- org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.12 "Console"
- org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.13 "Device"
- org.apache.cordova.device-motion 0.2.11 "Device Motion"
- org.apache.cordova.device-orientation 0.3.10 "Device Orientation"
- org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.11 "Notification"
- org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.11 "Geolocation"
- org.apache.cordova.globalization 0.3.3 "Globalization"
- org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.14 "Network Information"
- org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.12 "Vibration"
- org.chromium.zip 1.0.0 "Zip"

Comment: OK will take a look. Did try a local notification but it didn't fire, also sms didn't do anything.?

Comment: Sure, no problem, I'm glad I helped. I see you seem to be new to this site - if my answer proved useful to you consider it upvoting and marking as a correct answer. Thanks.